# Magento 2.4 Catalog_product_get_final_price Event not working with Observer

Tags: magento2, price

I want to create dynamic pricing for the products on the Magento 2 store. After much reading on the internet I understand this can be achieved by:

1. Create a custom module
2. Register the event and observer in `events.xml`
3. Update the product price in `Observer` file

I did all of these, however I'm not able to trigger the observer. Can someone please let me know what could be wrong here?

Relevant file contents:

- `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="catalog_product_get_final_price">
                <observer instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Catalog\ProductGetFinalPrice" name="dynamicprice"/>
        </event>
        <event name="catalog_product_prepare_index_select">
                <observer instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Catalog\ProductGetFinalPrice" name="dynamicprice"/>
        </event>
</config>
```

- `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/Catalog/ProductGetFinalPrice.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Catalog;

class ProductGetFinalPrice implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
            //Your observer code
           echo "Hello";
        $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testlog.log');
    $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Final Price Observer called..... ");
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $logger->info("Prodcut: ".$product);
    }
}
```

I have the `registation.php` and `module.xml` files in the module and it is successfully registered. However, I cannot catch any event in `testlog.log` file.

I have added a simple product
[image]

I expect to refresh this page and the event should trigger.

I event tried moving `events.xml` to `frontend` directory but still no good. I don't know how to debug this now. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own observer or debug the existing one i.e there are two similar events triggers from different classes, make sure you are using the correct one.

Event name: catalog_product_get_final_price
File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

Event name: catalog_product_get_final_price
File: vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Product/Price.php

Comment: I created my own observer(pasted above in question). I am still not receiving any events there. I don't see any logs. I want to override `getFinalPrice()` method.